# Summation form of the Hasse-Weil zeta function?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, zeta-functions

The only way I know to write the Hasse-Weil zeta function of an elliptic curve is as a product over the local zeta factors which are rational functions. To me, this appears like an Euler product.

Is there a natural summation version of the Hasse-Weil zeta function where the terms have some geometrical significance, say in analogy with the Dedekind zeta function?

I apologize for the naive question.

Comment: I mean, the coefficient of $n^{-s}$ parameterizes zero-cycles of norm $n$, where zero-cycles are formal sums of closed points of the arithmetic scheme, and the norm of a sum of closed points is the products of the orders of the closed points' residue fields.

Comment: My intuition is that the coefficient of $n^{-s}$ should be related to zero-cycles. So is it correct that the number of zero-cycles with norm $n$ is exactly this coefficient? Why is the zeta function not usually defined this way? Does the generic fiber enter? Thank you.

Comment: I recall that Serre gives such a definition in the [Proceedings of the Purdue conference on "Arithmetical Algebraic Geometry" (1965)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-gazette/article/abs/arithmetical-algebraic-geometry-ed-ofg-schilling-pp-vii-200-52s-1965-harper-and-row-new-york/D330D0F5FBCDF66E8D92C1BF822F0031#). For an affine scheme $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ of finite type one takes $\sum_I |R/I|^{-s}$ where the sum runs over ideals of finite index in $R$

Comment: @Kapil I don't think it can be quite that because as soon as $R$ has dimension $>1$ there are many ideals supported at a single point of a given degree.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. No, the generic fiber does not directly enter in this definition. Why is it not defined this way? One reason is that the summation perspective is not helpful in this setting for getting analytic information about the zeta function (as it is in the Dedekind case), and in fact the main known way to get analytic information is to factor the zeta function into automorphic $L$-functions, which is done most easily in the Euler product representation.

Comment: An (effective) zero cycle is a formal sum $\sum a_i p_i$ where the $p_i$ are closed points and the $a_i$ are nonnegative coefficients. The Euler product is $\prod_{p\ \text{a closed point}} (1+N(p)^{-s} + N(p)^{-2s} + \cdots)$, so expanding this product means choosing a nonnegative coefficient for each point $p$.

Comment: If you'd like some formal nonsense, if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime lying over the generic fiber, then $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is infinite, so $N(\mathfrak{p})$ should be infinity, and thus $N(\mathfrak{p})^{-s}$ should be zero. I would take this with several grains of salt, though.

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks. Maybe I need to read Serre's article more carefully! However, the number of ideals of given co-length supported at a point is still finite, so the sum may make sense.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer When we expand the Artin L-function of a (complex? $\ell$-adic works too when $n^{-s}$ is taken formally) representation we get $L(s,\rho)=\det(F(s))$ where $F(s)=\sum_n n^{-s} \prod_j \rho(Frob_{p_j})^{v_{p_j}(n)}$, here $\prod_j$ is a non-commutative product of matrices, assuming we fixed one for all an order on the primes. Do you know if there can / cannot be some ordering of primes making the obtained Dirichlet series with matrix coefficients $F(s)$ "meaningful" ? We can also add some conjugating factors $Q_j \rho(Frob_{p_j})Q_j^{-1}$ increasing the degree of freedom.

Comment: @reuns This seems to assume the sum of the determinant is the determinant of the sum, or some identity like that, which isn't accurate.

Comment: @WillSawin No, I'm just saying that $L(s,\rho)=\det(\prod_p (1-p^{-s} \rho(Frob_p))^{-1})$ obviously it is valid to expand the product, just need to be careful with the non-commutativity. One more possible degree of freedom (for algebraic curves): seing $\rho$ as a representation in $GL_n(\Bbb{A_Q})$ instead of $GL_n(\Bbb{Q_\ell})$.

Comment: @reuns Oh, I see, sorry. I think essentially there is too much freedom here and the Dirichlet series of matrices can never be made meaningful outside the abelian case, unfortunately...